# PostgreSQL: How to define PARAMETER in query?

Tags: postgresql

In MSSQL, I usually use below parameter like this:

```
declare @StartDate as date, @EndDate as date
set @StartDate  = '08/01/2015' set @EndDate = '08/15/2015'

----------- and use it here as my Date Range of Records:

Select * from Table_Name 
where DateRange between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

How can  I do this in PostgreSQL for generating reports/records?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this 
After $BODY$

```
DECLARE startdate date;
DECLARE enddate date;
```

After begin

```
startdate ='2015-08-01';
Enddate ='2015-08-15';

retrun query 

select * from Table where daterange between startdate and endate
```

Comment: result: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "date"
LINE 3: DECLARE startdate date;
                          ^
********** Error **********

Comment: @fLen its throwing error because you are executing this syntax directly.....use this syntax in your function then it will work fine.